# How can I join Excel sheet with point shapefile?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, openlayers-2

How can I join an Excel sheet with shapefile (Point) and common field is station code?

In Excel one station code has multiple rows and I want to attach those values with shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Would you be able to use the **edit** button beneath your question to update it with details of the software that you are using, please?  At the moment you have tags for QGIS, ArcGIS for Desktop and OpenLayers so we do not know.

Comment: Joins are one-to-one, that is one point 'sees' one row in the table, as you have said your station code has multiple entries which would mean you need to join Excel-to-Shapefile or investigate a relate which can relate one-to-many. Be careful joining to Excel, it would be best to save the table into a personal geodatabase with Microsoft Access to make the fields more stable.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66109/arcmap-perform-full-outer-join?s=1|3.3880

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS you can open the Project Properties dialog and there you will find a tab called relations, where you can have a one-to-many relationship between a spatial feature and several rows.

Have a look at this blog post, it describes how to use the feature:

http://fulcrumapp.com/blog/using-relations-in-qgis/

Comment: This solution works only if the data are stored in a database (PostGis, Sqlite etc..), or am I wrong?

Comment: @Vale: Yes, you are wrong.

Comment: @underdark, thank you! So there is something I do wrong because I tried and it didn't work.. in the example given above they are loading a feature class from a sqlite database, not a shapefile. I tried loading a point shapefile and created the relationship in the project properties but it didn't work...